# Some of custom font not working with `ie10`

Tags: html, css, fonts, internet-explorer-10

I am using custom font in my webpage. i am using 4 custom fonts, all it works with `chrome` and `firefox` but only one font (`RalewayMedium`) works in `ie10` rest not working.. what is the issue?

here is my fonts what i use :

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'OpenSansLight'; /*a name to be used later*/
    src: url('../fonts/OpenSans-Light.ttf'); /*URL to font*/
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'LatoRegular'; /*a name to be used later*/
    src: url('../fonts/Lato-Regular.ttf'); /*URL to font*/
}

@font-face { //only one works!
    font-family: 'RalewayMedium'; /*a name to be used later*/
    src: url('../fonts/Raleway-Medium.ttf'); /*URL to font*/
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'OpenSansRegular'; /*a name to be used later*/
    src: url('../fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf'); /*URL to font*/
}
```

Comment: http://www.localfont.com

Answer (score 1):

I guess it's working because you have the **Raleway** font set in your system.

To make web fonts cross browser compatible, you need to do it like this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyWebFont';
  src: url('webfont.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
       url('webfont.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
       url('webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```

Check out this [**article**](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/) for more information.

Comment: But i have installed all the fonts in my system. ex : Photoshop shows all fonts without any issue.

Comment: @3gwebtrain if you remove the `@font-face` set from your CSS, does it still work in Chrome or Firefox? If it doesn't, then you don't have those fonts in your system. Or, more likely the font name is not correct (missing white space or so) in your CSS.